# How do I print from windows xp to printer on airport extreme?

Tags: windows-xp, printer, airport-extreme

I've hooked up the printer to the USB port on my airport extreme basestation.  I can successfully print to the printer from my Mac.  When I read the AE manual on printing from windows xp, the instructions say, "Follow the on screen instructions to connect your printer."

Of course there aren't any on screen instructions.  Not sure what I'm suppose to do here.  When I look for the printer on the network (from my winxp machine) it doesn't show up.

I've followed these instructions with some success. 
http://tech.ifelix.net/1004.html

However, sometimes the whole document will not print.  It's pretty unreliable.

I know I have the right driver on win xp.  I have connected the printer directly to the winxp machine and I've printed that way.  So its something with the network, bonjour, AE...

Any suggestions on getting this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>If you have the printer on a static IP you can add a local printer and add a new TCP/IP port. Enter the IP of the printer and you should be printing.</s>
Disregard my previous answer. Have you installed **Bonjour for Windows** from the AirPort Utility CD on your Windows XP computer? If not you should do that first, then follow the instructions in Bonjour to add your printer.

Specifically, page 60 in [Designing AirPort Networks Using AirPort Utility](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/Designing_AirPort_Networks_10.5-Windows.pdf)

Comment: Do you know how to give a static IP to a printer on an airport extreme?

Comment: @brainbolton. You can't and don't need to. The IP for the printer is the IP of the Airport Extreme.

Comment: I thought I installed Bonjour for windows, but after reading this http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2586 I don't think I did.  I was mistaken in thinking that the airport utility also included bonjour.  When I get home today, I'll try out your suggestion.

Comment: I tried your suggestion.  It sorta worked.  Printing was really flaky though.  It would stop printing or it would only print part of a page.  I marked your question as the answer because this is how it should be working, but in my case its not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, download the [Bonjour software](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#bonjour). The wizard then walks you right to the connection. If you want to make the choice your default printer, be sure to follow the promopts to go "back" (prior to clicking "finish") so that you can check the "make default" box.